# Wait for external data to load before automatic calculations? Excel/VBA

Tags: vba, excel

First time poster, been searching for a solution to this all over but no luck yet.

To explain my problem:
TERMS:
OPC =  Object Linking and Embedding (OLE) for Process Control
(allows other applications to use data from PLC tags)
PLC = Programmable Logic Controller (computer for process control
SCADA = Supervisory Control And Data Acquisition (interface that displays values from PLC and allows control)

I have an excel workbook which is automatically opened by the SCADA system (WonderWare > Intouch, the software) at a specific time after the PLC has sorted some values. This workbook populates its cells using the OPC client, accessing them using this method:

```
=OPCLINK|EAST!'r[BELLWWPOWER]DailyValues_Z3[1,21]'
```

This works well but there are a lot of cells to populate so it takes a few seconds.

What I want to automatically happen is for these cells to populate and any calculations to complete before all the cells with formulas are changed to just the values of those formulas. The workbook is then saved under a new workbook name ("PowerReports-YesterdaysDate") with the VBA code stripped and both workbooks are closed (without saving the original, to preserve formulas).

This all works well except it happens too fast and the new saved copy ends up having just "#N/A" in all the cells with OPC links. When I had the first sheet's private sub as "Worksheet_Activate()" instead of "Worksheet_Calculate()", the code wouldn't stat automatically and waited for a mouse click onto one of the sheet's cells (FYI: the SCADA system opens this workbook to sheet 1 automatically to start with sheet 1's code). The new copy would save successfully in this case, but when the code stats automatically it is too fast. How can I wait for the external data to load before the calculations are done?

I've tried things (I don't know how successfully they were implemented..) like:
-Application.Calculate
-Application.RefreshAll
-Timers
-Trying to get a flag from the PLC
-Checking for remaining #N/As

It seems like if a loop or something similar is running right away it doesn't let the external data refresh.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    ' When first sheet "Main" is activated, all formulas are replaced
    ' with their calculated values. The second sheet, "Monthly Values" is then activated

    Dim rng As Range, r As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:D52")

    For Each r In rng
        If r.HasFormula Then
            r.Value = r.Value
        End If
    Next r

    Worksheets("Monthly Data").Activate

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    ' When second sheet "Monthly Values" is activated, all formulas are replaced
    ' with their calculated values. The sub routine, "SaveWithoutMacros" is then called

    Dim rng As Range, r As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:BJ84")

    'Worksheets("Monthly Data").Calculate
    'If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
    'DoEvents
    'End If

    For Each r In rng
        If r.HasFormula Then
            r.Value = r.Value
        End If
    Next r

    Call SaveWithoutMacros
End Sub

Sub SaveWithoutMacros()
    'Purpose : To save a copy of the active workbook without macros

    Dim vFilename As String
    Dim wbActiveBook As Workbook
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Following two lines causes an error in Excel 97 - comment them out

    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim VBComps As VBIDE.VBComponents
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------

    ' Save to filename in format (yesterdays date) "PowerReports-DD-MM-YYYY"
    vFilename = ("D:\PowerReports\" & "PowerReport-" _
    & Format(Date - 1, "DD-MMM-YYYY") & ".xls")

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs vFilename
    Set wbActiveBook = Workbooks.Open(vFilename)

    'Now strip all VBA, modules, userforms from the copy
    'This code is from Chip Pearson's website http://www.cpearson.com

    Set VBComps = wbActiveBook.VBProject.VBComponents

    For Each VBComp In VBComps
        Select Case VBComp.Type
        Case vbext_ct_StdModule, vbext_ct_MSForm, vbext_ct_ClassModule
            VBComps.Remove VBComp
        Case Else
            With VBComp.CodeModule
                .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
            End With
        End Select
    Next VBComp
    wbActiveBook.Save ' saves new version after code is stripped

    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True ' sets save flag to true, does not actually save
    Application.Quit ' quits entire application, all workbooks
End Sub
```

Sorry for the lengthy post, saw other people getting ripped on for not being detailed enough, haha.

Comment: worksheet.Calcuate is going to run all the time while the sheet is being populated , its not going to work out well for you.  Does SCADA always write to the same cells and would it always finish with the same cell (D52 possibly) as you could use that as a reference point to then save the values only (using .calulate to see if that cell has a value)

Comment: Ya it always fills in the same cells.

The saving values only part is working, but before the external OPC data has loaded, therefore the answers the calculations are #N/A because of the missing references.
How would I use .calculate to check if the external data had loaded yet?

Comment: at the moment every time a cell value changes .Calculate gets called co your pasting all the cells filled or not, so the formulas are changed to values as each cell is written. ill write you an answer up now with what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you now , by testing only the last cell being filled in then you will be sure all the data is in before you change them to values

Were basically telling worksheet_calculate to do nothing until the last cell has a formula

NOTE : SEE OP ANSWER BELOW FOR MODIFIED CODE THAT WORKED IN THIS SCADA SITUATION

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

        Dim rngLastCell As Range
        Set rngLastCell = Range("D52")

        If rngLastCell.HasFormula Then

            Dim rng As Range, r As Range
            Set rng = Range("A1:D52")


            For Each r In rng
                If r.HasFormula Then
                    r.Value = r.Value
                End If
            Next r

            Worksheets("Monthly Data").Activate
       End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out first thing monday =)!

Comment: This actually produced the same result, every cell that had a formula containing a reference to external data is "#N/A" in the new copy.

Comment: Wouldn't .HasFormula just check if the cell contained any formula, regardless if references in it were missing? I may try to do a similar thing as this but check if the last cell is still #N/A instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up getting it! Thanks to Steven Martin for giving me a jump off point to get this working, until you you posted your answer I didn't think an if statement would work for me here without a loop.

This is what worked for me:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Dim rngLastCell As Range
    Set rngLastCell = Range("D52")

    If WorksheetFunction.IsNA(rngLastCell) = False Then
        Dim rng As Range, r As Range
        Set rng = Range("A1:D52")

        For Each r In rng
            If r.HasFormula Then
                r.Value = r.Value
            End If
        Next r

        Worksheets("Monthly Data").Activate
   End If
End Sub
```

And then the same IF statement checking for "#N/A" in the 2nd sheet's code too, works like a charm now.

Comment: glad it worked for you,  very clever to use NA check to make sure ref are valid -  Keep in mind  ,Worksheet.Calculate is a loop in itself because it gets called everytime the sheet recalulates which is everytime a cell value changes while calculations is turned on